# format a number as I want

Tags: matlab, floating-point, rounding, precision, number-formatting

I have the number: `a = 3.860575156847749e+003;` and I would show it in a normal manner. So I write `b = sprintf('%0.1f' a);`. If I print `b` I will get: `3860.6`. This is perfect. Matter of fact, while `a` is a double type, `b` has been converted in char.

What can I do to proper format that number and still have a number as final result?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have to distinguish between both the numerical value (the number stored in your computer's memory) and its decimal representation (the string/char array you see on your screen). You can't really impose a format on a number: a number has a value which can be represented as a string in different ways (e.g. `1234 = 1.234e3 = 12.34e2 = 0.1234e4 = ...`).

If you want to store a number with less precision, you can use `round`, `floor`, `ceil` to calculate a number which has less precision than the original number.
E.g. if you have `a = 3.860575156847749e+003` and you want a number that only has 5 significant digits, you can do so by using `round`:

```
a = 3.860575156847749e+003;
p = 0.1; % absolute precision you want
b = p .* round(a./p)
```

This will yield a variable `b = 3.8606e3` which can be represented in different ways, but should contain zeros (in practice: very small values are sometimes unavoidable) after the fifth digit. I think that is what you actually want, but remember that for a computer this number is equal to `3.86060000` as well (it is just another string representation of the same value), so I want to stress again that the decimal representation is not set by rounding the number but by (implicitly) calling a function that converts the double to a string, which happens either by `sprintf`, `disp` or possibly some other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Result of sprintf y a text variable. have you tried to declare a variable as integer (for example) and use this as return value for sprintf instruction?

This can be useful to you: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/12/27/displaying-numbers-in-matlab/